# how to update record in codeIgniter using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I have created one function

```
<button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edit(school.school_ID)" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
```

pass to AngularJS controller

```
$scope.edit = function(id)
{
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url: 'mycontroller/myfun',

    }).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
    $scope.form = data;
    });
};
```

accessing in mycontroller/myfun

```
public function myfun(id)
    {
       $q = $this->db->get_where('tablename', array('school_ID' =>
        id));
        echo json_encode($q->row());
    }
```

Where is the problem

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: One problem I can see in the code is that id is not passed back to your CodeIgniter app.

Comment: I can't see any update query in your code. You just wrote select query.